# How to deploy aspnetcore app to ubuntu on digital ocean

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

After publishing my asp.net core 2.1 app to Digital Ocean on ubuntu server if i enter the server Ip in other to open the app in a browser I get this error:

Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/version (Ubuntu) Server at Server_IP Port 80

From this Line:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
at App_name.Data.ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line
```

When i lunch the app locally i check if no user exist then CreateAdminAccount creates an admin user.

Am sure the app cannot make any migrations before the app lunches in other to create the admin user.

I want to know how to apply the migration to the database when the app launches.

If I check the application logs I get this error too:

````
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1](Func4 beginMethod, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>cDisplayClass32_0.<<Open>gOpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func4 operation, Func4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger, Type contextType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
at Appname.Data.ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 94
— End of inner exception stack trace —
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Presscode.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>cDisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
—> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1](Func4 beginMethod, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>cDisplayClass32_0.<<Open>gOpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func4 operation, Func4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger1 logger, Type contextType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
at AppName.Data.ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration) in Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 94<—```
````

Comment: That looks like an issue between the application and connecting to Postgres. Is the DB on the same box, another box, is there any firewalling etc?

Comment: Did it ever work before or is this a first time deployment? If you publish it for the first time, I would check my appsettings.json and if you have set up an appsettings.development/production.json with the appropriate settings.

Comment: i am using a managed postgress database which is different from the droplet. This is a first time deployment